# How to add bookmark to IPython/Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm reading an interactive textbook ["Kalman and Bayesian Filters in Python"](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/table_of_contents.ipynb) and would like to mark where I left off when I go for a break. I have cloned the notebook and am running the notebook locally. My current method is to add a giant `####Bookmark` heading to my current `.ipynb` file. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why not just use a pair of Markdown cells?

Somewhere near the top:

```
Go to <a href=#bookmark1>my bookmark 1</a>
<br>
Go to <a href=#bookmark2>my bookmark 2</a>
```

In the cell for your first bookmark:

```
My First Bookmark <a name='bookmark1' />
```

In the cell for your second bookmark:

```
My Second Bookmark <a name='bookmark2' />
```

(Closing the `<a>` tag with no content inside stops it looking like a hyperlink)

Comment: This is a great answer, and you can expand upon it the way I have and create an entire notebook "index" with hyperlinks to all different parts of your notebook. (Hint, wherever you put a destination anchor, put an href back to your index.)  Also, I think keyword `id` is now preferable to `a` in the anchor tag.

Comment: Yes @RufusVS you are quite right, the `name` attribute in anchor has been deprecated.
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete

Also, the `id` could be in any element, doens't need to be `<a>`.

Comment: Oops, typo in my previous comment, it should read:
 Also, I think keyword `id` is now preferable to `name` in the anchor tag.

Comment: `Go to <a href='#bookmark'>my bookmark</a>` and `<a id='bookmark' />`

Comment: Jupyter automatically creates the `<a id="...">` tags when you use Markdown headings (`# My heading 1`, `## My heading 2`, etc.), which saves a little typing and gives a nice visual organization to the notebook as well.  To get the `href` value for your index or table of contents, right-click on the paragraph symbol that appears when you hover over the heading and "Copy link".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I can think of:

You can have multiple bookmarks by adding comments like: `#BOOKMARK1`, `#BOOKMARK_Ch2` etc in various cells, and then you can navigate to any of them by searching for the bookmark string in your browser (e.g. using `Ctrl+F`).